# Indicator of moving average of hourly volume bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to build a pine script which will give me a static histogram bar with the average value of volume for every hour.

e.g. the average of the last 5000 volume bars with time index 00.00, tha same for 01.00, 02.00, etc

I made this script woth python and pandas, but I don't know how to manage data in Pine script

My intention is to represent the chart with only 24 bars and not a rolling view with the previous values (see image below)

[image: Volume Hour average chart image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Average Hourly Volume Histogram", overlay=true)


hourlyVolumeAverages = array.new_float(24)
for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    hourlyVolumeAverages[i] = ta.sma(volume[hour == i and bar_index > max(0, bar_index - 4999)], 5000)

// Plot the histogram bars
plot(hourlyVolumeAverages, style=histogram, color=color.teal, linewidth=4)

hline(0, color=color.gray)
label.new(bar_index - 22, hourlyVolumeAverages[0], "00:00", yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none)
label.new(bar_index - 21, hourlyVolumeAverages[1], "01:00", yloc=yloc.price, style=label.style_none)
```

and so on for other hours